# Difference Between Service in the Constructor Versus Listed as a Provider in a Component?

Tags: angular, typescript

What would be the difference if in a component I declare a service as:

A provider:

```
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [MyService]})
```

Versus in the constructor:

```
constructor(private myService: MyService) {
    ...
}
```

Is there a preferred method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you register a provider at the component level, you get a new instance of the service with each new instance of that component.

When you provide the service at the root level, Angular creates a single, shared instance of MyService and injects it into any class that asks for it.

Registering the provider in the @Injectable() metadata also allows Angular to optimize an app by removing the service from the compiled app if it isn't used.

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
```